# Shared Assembly Info File breaks Unit Testing

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mstest, assemblyinfo

I have a series of C# class projects with matching Unit Testing Projects.
Everything works fine until I introduce a SharedAssemblyInfo.cs file.

I added the file to the solution, then in each project I added a 'Link' to it and dropped it into the Properties section.

I am able to build without issue (my libraries are created just fine) but when I try to run my Unit Tests I get an IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly.

Anyone ever see this or now what is missing?

I could just take out the SharedAssemblyInfo file but really would prefer to have a central location for versioning and other common data.

I found this works but do not understand why this matters:
If I have the following in the AssemblyInfo files, the exception is thrown:

```
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("en-US")]
```

If I have the following in the AssemblyInfo Files, no exception:

```
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
```

Some Specs:

- .NET 4.6.1
- C# 6 Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 2
- MS Test

Comment: OK Figured out my issue but would love for someone to explain this one to me.  When I have the following in my AssemblyInfo file:
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("en-US")] => Exception
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")] => OK

Comment: You should probably edit your comment into your question so that it more obviously becomes part of what you are asking.  A lot of people seem to skip over comments before attempting to answer..

Comment: Fair point, I will do that